# How to extract each part of the line from the group chat using python?

Tags: regex, python-3.x

I have a text file of group conversations which I'm trying to analyze. It looks like this:

```
[4/30/18, 5:49:51 PM] ‪+11 11 111 1111: Thanks for the recommendation. 
[4/30/18, 5:51:21 PM] Joe Johnson: It's a pleasure to know you! 
[4/30/18, 6:00:55 PM] ‪+11 1 11 1111 1111: Nice!
[4/30/18, 6:22:01 PM] ‪+1 (111) 111‑111: sure.. I will look into.
```

I need to extract every part of each line: date, time, username and the message.

I have been able to separate the Dates and Times using the re package in python by using the code below:

```
date_regex = re.compile(r'(\d+/\d+/\d+)')
date = date_regex.findall(watsup_content)
time_regex = re.compile(r'(\d{1,2}:\d{2}:\d{2} AM|\d{1,2}:\d{2}:\d{2} PM)')
time = time_regex.findall(watsup_content)
```

However, I'm having problems getting the users (which sometimes have foreign numbers and sometimes have names) as well as the actual messages which are after the Colon.

I was thinking of using an in-between function for two patterns to get the users... however not sure how to do it... I also don't know how to get the actual messages as well. Your help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do you need to use `re` even for author and content?

Comment: Yes, please. It's ok for me to have some names, domestic, and foreign numbers. As long as I have some reference.

Comment: I can provide a simple solution without using `re`. Is it ok?

Comment: Thank you. That would be great.

Comment: The main question is: are colons allowed to use in the nicknames? If so, it's almost impossible to precisely split lines into parts

Comment: no colons in nicknames/usernames/phone numbers

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
import re

with open('myfile.txt', 'r') as f:
    content = f.readlines()

date_regex = re.compile(r'(\d+/\d+/\d+)')
time_regex = re.compile(r'(\d{1,2}:\d{2}:\d{2} AM|\d{1,2}:\d{2}:\d{2} PM)')

for line in content:
    print(line)
    date = date_regex.findall(line)
    time = time_regex.findall(line)
    content = ":".join(line.split(':')[3:]).strip()
    author = line.split(']')[-1].split(':')[0].strip()
    print(date)
    print(time)
    print(author)
    print(content)
    print('---')
```

and you get:

```
[4/30/18, 5:49:51 PM] ‪+11 11 111 1111: Thanks for the recommendation: bye! 

['4/30/18']
['5:49:51 PM']
‪+11 11 111 1111
Thanks for the recommendation: bye!
---
[4/30/18, 5:51:21 PM] Joe Johnson: It's a pleasure to know you! :D:D

['4/30/18']
['5:51:21 PM']
Joe Johnson
It's a pleasure to know you! :D:D
---
[4/30/18, 6:00:55 PM] ‪+11 1 11 1111 1111: Nice! :X

['4/30/18']
['6:00:55 PM']
‪+11 1 11 1111 1111
Nice! :X
---
[4/30/18, 6:22:01 PM] ‪+1 (111) 111‑111: sure.. I will look into. ::)

['4/30/18']
['6:22:01 PM']
‪+1 (111) 111‑111
sure.. I will look into. ::)
```

Comment: Will work until someone uses a colon in a message :)

Comment: Every programmer is a soothsayer a little bit :) I mean it's an obvious guess, if this is a chat room, eventually someone will use a smiley face and the code will break. It's an easy fix though. PS (I am not the question author)